# How to get latest changes from master branch into feature branch?

Tags: git, gitlab

I was working on a feature branch and then I found a codegap which needs  to filled in by  other developer.
If his changes has been merged in `master`, how can I get those changes in my branch, keeping in mind I haven't committed any changes in my new branch nor pushed my branch to server.

Do I need to rebase ?

Answer (score 0):

If you can, you could rebase your feature branch on top of master: your feature branch would then include that commit in its ancestors.  *I would recommand committing your work in progress on that branch first.
Then:

```
git checkout feature
git rebase master
```

But it could also include other commits you might not want in your feature branch.
If that is the case, then a workaround would be to use [`git cherry-pick`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick), to import a specific commit into your feature branch.

Comment: i got no issues with rebasing  and getting all the unwanted changes as well from the master . Thanks will do that